# Two DIVs one above the other without deforming

Tags: html, css

This is my problem, I have two `<div>` exactly the same, one above the other, when I write something I the one that's behind the other one. The "forward" `<div>` moves down. (not easy to explain sorry)

Here example:

```
<div class="box1">TEXT THAT DEFORM box11 <div class="box11"></div></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box1
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 16vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.box11
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url(../medias/box1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 70% 50%;
}
```

Thanks

**IMAGES**

This is what I want:
[image]

And this is what happen when I  write on the first DIV:
[image]

Comment: What's the question Boris I've just run this in my server and it looks like a text box with a title? No deformation for me...

Comment: Nop i dont have the level to show you a screnshots, let me upload a pic somewhere. 2 secs pls

Comment: You said the divs are "exactly the same" but one div have `width:100%` while the other have the `width:90%`. Their heights are different aswell. Rewrite this question, please.

Comment: I know thats confusing but the 100% is in its parent so that doesn't cause an issue

Comment: This is what happen when I write on the "behind" div : http://pasteboard.co/1SvwkkaN.png                                                               And this is what I want: http://pasteboard.co/1SvzPsrA.png

Comment: Simply don't write in the parent div? Unless you don't give the children div an absolute/fixed position this is the default behaviour... I can't understand your problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you need to do, you set the parent (`box1`) to `position: relative` and the child (`box11`) to `position: absolute`. This way it doesn't get affected by the text written in the parent as it is taken out of the flow and as such float on top of its content.

To keep the `position: absolute` child related to its parent, the parent also needs to have positioning other than `static`, in this case I used `relative`.

```css
.box1
{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 16vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.box11
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(../medias/box1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 70% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">TEXT THAT DEFORM box11 <div class="box11"></div></div>
```